# Login website with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, lxml

I'm trying to login to a webpage using python 3 using requests and lxml. However, after sending a post request to the login page, I can't enter pages that are available after login. What am I missing?

```
import requests
from lxml import html

session_requests = requests.session()

login_URL = 'https://www.voetbal.nl/inloggen'
r = session_requests.get(login_URL)

tree = html.fromstring(r.text)
form_build_id = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='form_build_id']/@value")))[0]

payload = {
    'email':'mom.soccer@mail.com',
    'password':'testaccount',
    'form_build_id':form_build_id
    }

headers = {
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language':'nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarymGk1EraI6yqTHktz',
    'Host':'www.voetbal.nl',
    'Origin':'https://www.voetbal.nl',
    'Referer':'https://www.voetbal.nl/inloggen',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36'
    }

result = session_requests.post(
    login_URL,
    data = payload,
    headers = headers
)

pvc_url = 'https://www.voetbal.nl/club/BBCB10Z/overzicht'
result_pvc = session_requests.get(
    pvc_url,
    headers = headers
)

print(result_pvc.text)
```

The account in this sample is activated, but it is just a test-account which I created to put my question up here. Feel free to try it out.

Comment: I suspect a successful login will be returning a cookie which you need to store and present for each subsequent page. Have a look at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies

Comment: As a follow-up to the above, try adding cookies=result.cookies to your last get request

Comment: You'll have to use the `files` parameter for your login data, and you don't need all those headers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think you're right about the cookies; however, adding them doesn't seem to fix the problem.

When printing results.cookies I get: <RequestsCookieJar[]>... suppose there should be cookies in them?

Comment: Actually you don't have to use `files`, just add this `'form_id': 'voetbal_login_login_form'` to `payload`

Comment: @t.m.adam : thanks for that comment. I think that one was missing as well. However, still can't get it to work. I think it has something to do with the cookies. When loggin in, I see that request cookies are sent to the website. These cookies seem to remain the same over different sessions, so I tried to add them manually in my script ( cookies={'_ga':'GA1.2.934627523.1516195732', 
    'cookieNotification':'ok', etc....}

But no success... any ideas?

Comment: Also; I put a content-Type (WebKitFormBoundary, followed by a random string) in the headers. This WebKitFormBoundary followed by a random string is also visible in the payload, but the string seems to be dynamic. Could this be the problem? And where can I find the dynamic part?

Comment: You don't need any headers, and you don't have to set the cookies manually - that defeats the purpose of your question. Just change the payload and you should be able to login.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

there where multiple problems:

Payload: 'form_id': 'voetbal_login_login_form'  was missing. Thanks @t.m.adam

Cookies: request cookies where missing. They seem to be static, so I tried to add them manually, which worked. Thanks @match and @Patrick Doyle

Headers: removed the 'content-type' line; which contained a dynamic part.

Login works like a charm now!

Comment: Could you post the code you needed to change to fix the issues instead of just describing the fixes, please?